# Android: Closing output streams if data is constantly written to disk?

Tags: android, stream

I have a question regarding streams. I use them in order to write data to a file on my external sd card. Normally, a best practice is to close all streams when they are not needed anymore. But what if I'm constantly writing data to my storage device, like multiple times a second? Is it better to leave the stream open instead of closing it?

Comment: You don't have to close the streams if you keep using it every few seconds.. Because re-opening and closing the stream is an expensive operation for memory. Close the streams when you're done using it for good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's better to close streams when they are not needed but if they are in use never close them till you finish as @sharp said opening stream is expensive operation and doing that constantly will slow your app and increase it's memory usage.
but keep in mind with this scenario you should care of exception handling
and where you should close stream because If streams are not closed, the underlying operating system can't free native resources.
take a look on [Java Anti-Patterns](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php)  and [PerformanceTechniques](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques)

if you are using modern java JDK you should have a look on
[try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)
then you will never have to close streams explicitly. (that's the reason try-with-resources was added in the first place.)
{From java Doc}
"The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is as an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The `try-with-resources` statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, which includes all objects which implement `java.io.Closeable`, can be used as a resource."

Comment: Thank you very much :) I don't use the try with resources statement. Instead I leave the stream open and close it when it is supposed to be closed, e.g. when the application is quitted.

Comment: it's better to follow try with resources approach it's provided to be used in your case